# Updating core data performance

Tags: ios, performance, core-data

I'm creating an app that uses core data to store information from a web server. When there's an internet connection, the app will check if there are any changes in the entries and update them. Now, I'm wondering which is the best way to go about it. Each entry in my database has a last updated timestamp. Which of these 2 will be more efficient:

1. Go through all entries and check the timestamp to see which entry needs to be updated.
2. Delete the whole entity and re-download everything again.

Sorry if this seems like an obvious question and thanks!

Comment: do you have control over the implementation of web-server ? Like incase you can change the web-services ?

Comment: Yes I have control :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say option `1` would be most efficient, as there is rarely a case where downloading everything (especially in a large database with large amounts of data) is more efficient than only downloading the parts that you need.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did something similiar.

I solve the problem, by assigning an unique ID and a global 'updated timestamp' and thinking about 'delta' change.

I explain better, I have a global 'latest update' variable stored in user preferences, with a default value of 01/01/2010.

This is roughly my JSON service:

```
response: {
  metadata: {latestUpdate: 2013...ecc}
  entities: {....}
}
```

Then, this is what's going on:

1. pass the 'latest update' to the web service and retrieve a list of entities
2. update the core data store
3. if everything went fine with core data, the 'latestUpdate' from the service metadata became my new 'latest update variable' stored in user preferences

That's it. I am only retrieving the needed change, and of course the web service is structured to deliver a proper list. Which is: a web service backed by a database, can deal with this matter quite well, and leave the iphone to be a 'simple client' only.

But I have to say that for small amount of data, it is still quite performant (and more bug free) to download the whole list at each request.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have about 300 entries...should I just redownload everything every time it connects to the net?

Comment: Well "network speaking" can be quite a few data. If you also have much text in each entity, I would do some test, especially with a device connected to 3G network.

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion in the comments above, you can model your core data object entries with version control like this

```
CoreDataEntityPerson:
     name : String
     name_version : int
     image : BinaryData
     image_version : int
```

You can now model the server xml in the following way:

```
  <person>
      <name>michael</name>
      <name_version>1</name_version>
      <image>string_converted_imageData</image>
      <image_version>1</image_version>
  </person>
```

Now, you can follow the following steps :

1. When the response arrives and you parse it, you initially create a new object from entity and fill the data directly.
2. Next time, when you perform an update on the server, you increase the version count of an entry by 1 and store it.
   E.g. lets say the name michael is now changed to abraham, then version count of name_version on server will be 2
3. This updated version count will come in the response data.
4. Now, while storing the data in the same object, if you find the version count to be same, then the data update of that entry can be skipped, but if you find the version count to be changed, then the update of that entry needs to be done.

This way you can efficiently perform check on each entry and perform updates only on the changed entries.

Advice:

1. The above approach works best when you're dealing with large amount of data updation.
2. In case of simple text entries for an object, simple overwrite of data on all entries is efficient enough. And this also keeps the data reponse model simple.